# MongoDB check if a key exists and has a specific value

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm absolute beginner in MongoDB and I have a problem which I can't solve.

I have a Request collection which looks like this:

```
{ ->document one
id...
Category:[Car]
Color:[Black,White]
Fuel Type:[Diesel, Gasoline]
}

{ ->document two
id..
Category:[Car]
}
```

I have a Product object in JavaScript which looks like this:

```
let newObj: {
    Category: 'Car',
    Model: 'BMW',
    'Production age': 1997,
    'Fuel Type': 'Diesel',
    Color: 'White',
    'Mileage (km)': '75213',
    Price: '9000',
    Electric: 'Yes',
    'Mile range': '300'
  }
```

I want to get all documents from Request collection which contains one of the keys and a specific value. To understand better:

In my case the Category=Car and the Color=White so I want to return back both of the documents.
If the Category=Car but the Color=Red I want to return only the second document
If the other fields doesn't exists I don't care about them only about the matched ones.

```
let findArgs={}
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(product.newObj)) {
                filterArgs[key]={$exists: true,$in:[value]}
}

let result= await requestColl.aggregate([
        {$match: filterArgs },
        {$sort: {[sortBy]:order}},
        ]).toArray();
```

This is the filterArgs query which will be in {match:}

```
{
  Category: { '$exists': true, '$in': [ 'Car' ] },
  Model: { '$exists': true, '$in': [ 'BMW' ] },
  'Production age': { '$exists': true, '$in': [ 1997 ] },
  'Fuel Type': { '$exists': true, '$in': [ 'Diesel' ] },
  Color: { '$exists': true, '$in': [ 'White' ] },
  'Mileage (km)': { '$exists': true, '$in': [ '75213' ] },
  Electric: { '$exists': true, '$in': [ 'Yes' ] },
  'Mile range': { '$exists': true, '$in': [ '300' ] }
}
```

How can I acheive the above mentioned? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I tried to do a query like this but still due to that Car exists in both documents I can't get the specific one.

```
{ $or:  
   [  { $and: [{ Category: { '$in': [ 'Car' ]}}]},  
      { $and: [ { Category: { '$in': [ 'Car' ]}}, { Color: { '$in': [ 'White' ] }}]}      
]}
```

Comment: Your question shows only one document. What other document are you referring to?

Comment: On that collection example each item starting with id.. is a document. But I re-update it to see it bettter. Thanks for your comment.